# AngularJs throw error with url ending by /#xxx when hashPrefix is set to "!" : Uncaught Error: [$location:ihshprfx]

Tags: angularjs

Some of our partners include links to our website such as https://www.lapetitetranche.fr/#b4sqF

Our application is using `!`  as hash prefix, so Angular thinks something is wrong and throws an error, but it's not a wrong URL.

`Uncaught Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "https://www.lapetitetranche.fr/#b4sqF", missing hash prefix "#!".`

I just want angular to ignore this parameter and simply load the same page as https://www.lapetitetranche.fr . How can I do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do exactly what you want.

The only solution is to use the html5 mode of the angular router.
In this case you have to create the server routes whitch will redirect to your home page.

Otherwise, if you wan't don't want use the HTML5 mode you may use this little hack to prevent the angular behaviour.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash.indexOf('#/')  == 0) {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

---

edit: (from comment)

```
if(hash.indexOf('#!') < 0 && 
    hash.indexOf('#') == 0 && 
    hash.indexOf('?#') < 0 && 
    hash.indexOf('?') != 0 && 
    hash.indexOf('#state') < 0 ){

    window.location.hash = '#!'; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, now working with the following :
if(hash.indexOf('#!') < 0 && hash.indexOf('#') == 0){
window.location.hash = '#!';
}

Comment: My previous comment make our facebook oAuth fail, now working with the following : if(hash.indexOf('#!') < 0 && hash.indexOf('#') == 0 && hash.indexOf('?#') < 0 && hash.indexOf('?') != 0 && hash.indexOf('#state') < 0 ){

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the angular routing process by using `target="_self"` in the `<a>` tags which you want to use hash linking.  Angular will treat the link as an external page, but the page will still load in the same browser tab.

Comment: The link is from an external website